# Python lambda with any()

Tags: python, lambda, any

I have a list of words in a list `self.terms`, and a string `line`. If any of the terms in the list are in `line`, I'd like to write them out to a file `terms_file`.

I used `any()` as shown below, but this returns a boolean.

```
any(terms_file.write(term) for term in self.terms if term in line)
```

How can I write out to the file? I tried adding a lambda but I'm not really familiar with them and that did not work. I got some syntax errors, but after some changes, I got `False` returned again.

Is it possible to do this using `any()`?

Comment: Did you want to write *all* terms, or only the first one that matched?

Comment: To whoever voted to close and downvotes, can you explain why this is "not a real question"? It is a perfectly "real" question about any() function in lambda. I apologise if I don't have 10 years of Python experience that his may sound "too easy" or irrelevant for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `any()` here; you don't even use the return value.

To write all matching terms, use:

```
terms_file.write(''.join(term for term in self.terms if term in line))
```

but it'd be better to just use a regular loop; readability counts!

```
for term in self.terms:
    if term in line:
        terms_file.write(term)
```

Use `any()` only if you want to know about the boolean result of the test; `any()` stops iterating when it finds the first `True` value. In your case `terms_file.write()` returns `None`, so it'll never even encounter `True` and *always* return `False`.

Comment: Or: `terms_file.write(''.join(filter(lambda term: term in line, self.terms)))` if you prefer `lambda` and `filter` to a filtering generator statement.

Answer (score 0):

`any` will tell you whether any of the terms where present in `line` (hence the name).

You can just create a list of those terms:

```
present_terms = list(terms_file.write(term) for term in self.terms if term in line)
```

and write that to a file, possibly after joining the list items:

```
out_file.write(' '.join(present_terms))
```